# How can I cache a nix derivations's dependencies when built via Docker?

Tags: nix

```
FROM nixos/nix@sha256:af330838e838cedea2355e7ca267280fc9dd68615888f4e20972ec51beb101d8
# FROM nixos/nix:2.3
ADD . /build
WORKDIR /build
RUN nix-build
ENTRYPOINT /build/result/bin/app
```

I have the very simple Dockerfile above that can succesfully build my application. However each time I modify any of the files within the application directory (`.`), it'll have to rebuild from scratch + download all the nix store dependencies.

Can I somehow grab a "list" of store dependencies downloaded and then add them in on the beginning of the Dockerfile for the purpose of caching them independently (for the ultimate goal of saving time + bandwidth)?

I'm aware I could build this docker image using nix natively which has it's own caching functionality (well the nix store), but I'm trying to have this buildable in a  non nix environment (hence using docker).

Comment: Perhaps you could use Docker Build Secrets to use cachix.org credentials in your Dockerfile. https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/#new-docker-build-secret-information

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest split source in two parts. The idea is to create a separate Docker layer with dependencies only, which changes rarely:

```
FROM nixos/nix:2.3
ADD ./default.nix /build
# if you have any other Nix files, put them to ./nix subdirectory
ADD ./nix /build/nix
# now let's download all the dependencies
RUN nix-shell --run exit

# At this point, Docker has cached all the dependencies. We can perform the build
ADD . /build
WORKDIR /build
RUN nix-build
ENTRYPOINT /build/result/bin/app
```